# How do I use an object of a class as an instance variable?

Tags: java, class, constructor, initialization, instance-variables

My professor gave us these instructions:

This class should have two instance variables: an integer `radius` and a `Point2D` object `center` that denotes the center of the Circle. Provide the following functionality: A two parameter constructor that initializes the instance variables, in the order radius and center.

I need help with the making `center` an instance variable. This is what I have:

```
public class Circle
{
//instance variables
   private int radius;
   Point2D center = new Point2D(2,3);

//constructor
   public Circle(int radius, int center)
   {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.center = center;
   }
}
```

I'm not sure how to use it as an instance variable and I don't know how to initialize it in the constructor method.

Comment: You have it already.

Comment: If I understood your questions right, then what you are doing is right Point2D center = new Point2D(2,3); is an instance variable and you are assigning parameter from constructor to 'center' instance variable. I think you are confused with the terminology of java variable type . There are four variable types (ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: it doesnt compile. gives me an error that says, "incompatible types: Int cannot be converted into Point2D

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change the second parameter of your contructor from int to Point2D object like this:

```java
public class Circle
{
    //instance variables
    private int radius;

    // Remove the initialization from here and move it inside constructor
    Point2D center;

    //constructor
    // Here you change the second parameter from "int center" to "Point2D center"
    public Circle(int radius, Point2D center)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.center = center;
    }
}
```

This way, you are initializing your instance variables inside your constructor and made it easier for testing and stuff since your class is not depending on Point2D class.

Comment: Yes!! THANK YOU!!

Comment: @KoulaeMoua kindly read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and follow the advice it gives

Answer (score 0):

center is correcly defined as an instance variable. There is however no need to assign it to anything while declaring it since you ask for center in the constructor. The only error in your code is the constructor which wrongly says that center should be of type int instead of Point2D.

I wont give you the full answer in code as it obviously is a school assignment and what I already said should help you plenty. Good luck